# MonoDroid Format New TableRow to Fit TableLayout

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Can't seem to find any examples of this being done from the activity. I can get the table row added to the table layout, but it doesn't line up with the existing columns that were set up in the axml. All I want is to have my header row set up in axml and then dynamically add to it from the activity.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scannedLO"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below ="@id/addPart"
android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
android:stretchColumns="3">
<TableRow  android:layout_marginBottom ="10dip">
  <TextView
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:text="Item Number"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:layout_margin="2dip"/>
  <TextView
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:text="Item Description"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:layout_margin="2dip"/>
  <TextView
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:text="Qty"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:layout_margin="2dip"
    android:lines="1"/>
</TableRow>
```

When I do this in my activity:

```
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.scannedLO);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView itemNumber = new TextView(this);
        TextView itemDescription = new TextView(this);
        TextView itemQuantity = new TextView(this);

                    TableRow.LayoutParams trparam = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
                    trparam.Span = 3;

                    itemNumber.Text = partnum;
                    itemDescription.Text = partdescr;
                    itemQuantity.Text = partquan;

                    tr.AddView(itemNumber);
                    tr.AddView(itemDescription);
                    tr.AddView(itemQuantity);

                    tl.AddView(tr);
```

All 3 of my textviews end up in the first column.

Comment: Anybody?  I just want a dynamic tablelayout which seems like something monodroid should be able to handle.  Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setLayoutParams()` method in Java maps to the [`LayoutParameters`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=P%3aAndroid.Views.View.LayoutParameters) property in C#.

```
row.LayoutParameters = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent;
```

In general, when translating from Java to C#, getter/setter methods in Java are mapped to properties in C#. For example, `getText()` / `setText()` in Java will usually map to a property named `Text` in C#.

**Edit (based on your updated question):**

The problem is that you're setting the column for each TextView in the XML, but you're not doing that in code:

```
itemNumber.LayoutParameters = new TableRow.LayoutParams(1);
itemDescription.LayoutParameters = new TableRow.LayoutParams(2);
itemQuantity.LayoutParameters = new TableRow.LayoutParams(3);
```

After doing that the views should go in the proper columns. They won't line up perfectly, since in the XML you're applying padding and margin, but are not doing that in code either. I'd suggest creating reusable styles for the cells instead of redefining those everywhere.

Comment: Thanks.  There is still a lot more formatting I need to do.  I just need a comprehensive example of formatting tablelayouts in mono from the activity.  Do you know where one might be?  Google hasn't yielded any worth while results.

Comment: You will probably have much better luck finding what you're looking for in Java, and it's pretty straightforward to translate from Java -> C# (as we did here). A more comprehensive look at Mono for Android's API design, and it's relationship with the Java side, is available here: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/api_design

Comment: I get this when using your example.  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What version of MfA are you running? It's possible that they moved the definition from int->enum in a more recent version.

Comment: Just downloaded last week so I assume the latest and greatest.  I've added more information to the post to hopefully explain better what I'm after.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I knew there had to be a way to set column somewhere but couldn't figure it out.